# What does this piece of code mean?

Tags: python, list

Can someone explain these lines of code please so I can break it down to several lines of code?

```
q = [w[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(q),3)]
for x,y,z in grid:
    print(x,y,z)
```

By the way, "`q`" is a list containing words.
 Any explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code loops through `word` with a step size of 3 and groups every 3 consecutive words.

Let's say `word = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Over the course of the loop, `i` will be `= 0, 3, 6`

To `grid`, you append `word[0:3]`,`word[3:6]`,`word[6:9]`

So `grid` will have in it `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

```
for x,y,z in grid:
    print(x,y,z)
```

This just prints the contents. Each element on a separate line.

I feel that running the code will tell you what's happening. Or were you wondering how it works (e.g. list comprehension).

Comment: This is great! I was wondering that is it possible to break down this line of code?